# ej2.syncfusion Calendar Schedule Header

Tags: angular, scheduler, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

Can we edit Header of the scheduler from one position to other or can we Edit  Tag?

I want header should look something like .[image]

But in ej2.Syncfusion Calendar Schedule We get Header like.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNe4K.png) 1st image is the what, I want to achieve.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfRKV.png) ej2.Syncfusion Calendar Scheduler Header

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared a sample based on your requirement which can be viewed from the below link.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-schedule-ar-locale?file=views.component.ts

Kindly try the above sample and let us know if you need further assistance.